# How to prevent entering wrong dates in react-admins DateInput?

Tags: react-native, material-ui, react-admin

How to prevent user from manually entering wrong dates like 30.Feb.2020?

[image]

```
import { DateInput } from "react-admin";
const validateDate = (value) => {
        console.debug('value of the date is ',value);
        // In case of wrong date like 30.Feb.2020 the value is empty, so no chance to validate the correctness.
    if(isCorrect(value)){
        return undefined
    }
    return 'error'
};


<DateInput validate={[validateDate]} source={'myDate'}></DateInput>
```

I try to validate the date, but it is **in case of wrong date just empty (undefined)**, so no chance to validate or distinguish between empty or wrong date.

How to prevent user from entering wrong dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module to validate the date. for example using moments

```
const isValidDate = (toTest) => moment(toTest, "D/M/YY", true).isValid()
```

Comment: My problem is not the validation itself. As I stated is, that the value (in your case toTest) is empty if the date is entered as 02/30/2020. The value isn't filled, so how can I validate?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Can you please add the import statement for `DateInput`. Some modules will validate the input for you and that seems to be the case here but you should make sure in the docs

Comment: I added the import statement in the question. DateInput is from React-Amin. I didn't found anything in the docs.

Comment: you can take a look at the code here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/DateInput.tsx . it looks like the module converts the data you enter to a date object on line 45 and I have a feeling that if the date is invalid it will fail and you will get nothing. I haven't tested it so you should. If that is the case you don't need to validate the date